# Condition given in solution of PDE contains reference to symbol not in solution

Tags: differential-equations

Solving the initial value problem for a two-dimensional heat equation
inside a circle (of radius $a=1$) $u_t = k \nabla^2 u$ with $k=1$ with time-independent boundary conditions:

\begin{align*}
    u(1,\theta,t) &= 0
\end{align*}
And initial conditions $u(r,\theta,0) =(r-r^3)\sin\theta$. There is an implied periodic boundary
conditions on $\theta$
\begin{align*}
    u(r,-\pi,t) &= u(r,\pi,t)\\
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(r,-\pi,t) &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}(r,\pi,t)
\end{align*}

In picture:

[image]

Mathematica gives solution, which I assume now is correct, but in solution it says

```
      (K[1] | K[3]) \[Element] Integers && K[1] >= 1 && K[3] >= 1
```

But there is no `K[1]` anywhere in the solution. There is only `K[3]`.

What could  `K[1]` mean?

Code

```
ClearAll[u, r, t, theta];
a = 1;
pde = D[u[r, theta, t], t] == Laplacian[u[r, theta, t], {r, theta}, "Polar"];
bcOnR = u[a, theta, t] == 0;
bcOnTheta = {u[r, -Pi, t] == u[r, Pi, t], Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][r, -Pi, t] == Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][r, Pi, t]};
ic = u[r, theta, 0] == (r - r^3)*Sin[theta];
sol = DSolve[{pde, bcOnR, bcOnTheta, ic}, u[r, theta, t], {r, theta, t}, Assumptions -> 0 < r <= a]
```

It gives

[image]

And

```
InputForm[sol]
{{u[r, theta, t] -> Piecewise[{{Inactive[Sum][(4*BesselJ[1, r*BesselJZero[1, K[3]]]*BesselJ[3, BesselJZero[1, K[3]]]*
         Sin[theta])/(E^(t*BesselJZero[1, K[3]]^2)*BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[1, K[3]]]^2*BesselJZero[1, K[3]]^2), 
       {K[3], 1, Infinity}], Element[K[1] | K[3], Integers] && K[1] >= 1 && K[3] >= 1}}, Indeterminate]}}
```

You can see, there is no `K[1]` anywhere in solution. So what is it?

Version 12.2 on windows 10